# How do I handle webapp users in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Previously I was using databases from BaaS (Backend as a Service) - Parse, Backendless, Firebase - this services has everything I need to manage users of my webapps: tokens handling, owner policies etc.

How do I manage webapp users in own database? (PostgreSQL 9.4)

1. Is it suppose to be just a regular table, which will contain columns "login", "password" etc. or there are specific tools to implement that?
2. How should I handle tokens? Should I store it somehow in database, or tokens suppose to be stored in my server and are not bind to database at all?
3. How do I implement owner policies? Are there some specific tools in Postgres for this, or I should simply create the column "ownerId" in each table and use it as Foreign Key?

If you know good articles on this topic - please, post a links - it will be very helpful!
I would search for it in google, but I've found nothing but articles about database users handling. I assume, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regular table or postgrsql `ROLE` system
2. Usually tokens are on application side
3. Postgres 9.5 have row security policies but you can implement owner policy by yourself. Hard to say what database features you have to use without 
   assumptions of the project.